# Case when query taking very long time even when no records found

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, max

Any alternatives for case when when we need maximum of the two dates as audit date
How to optimise it.

```
SELECT 
  a.code,a.name,b.token,a.last_updated,b.last_updated, 
  CASE WHEN a.last_updated >= nvl(b.last_updated, a.last_updated) THEN 
  a.last_updated ELSE b.last_updated END AS currdate 
FROM 
  table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.code = b.code 
    AND b.last_updated > '03/10/2018 13:21:37') 
WHERE 
  a.ou_code IN 
  (SELECT ou_code FROM table1 WHERE last_updated > '03/10/2018 13:21:37') 
  OR (b.last_updated > '03/10/2018 13:21:37') 
ORDER BY currdate
```

Comment: Remove `OR (b.last_updated > '03/10/2018 13:21:37') `. It's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your tables don't have the proper indexes. If you can, I would add:

```
create index ix1 on table2 (code, last_updated);

create index ix2 on table1 (last_updated);
```